# How to put Picasso downloaded image as extra in intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, picasso

I have a list where each item has an image and description. The images are downloaded using Picasso in the list adapter.

When a list item is clicked I want to display that image in another activity.

I can't retrieve the image bitmap directly from the `ImageView` reference with this `((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

When I checked the class type of the drawable retrieved this way it is a `PicassoDrawable` and it can't be casted to `BitmapDrawable`.

How do I get the image data (retrieved using Picasso) to pass as extra in the intent?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a list where each item has an image and description. The images
>   are downloaded using Picasso in the list adapter. When a list item is
>   clicked I want to display that image in another activity.

`Picasso` takes care of caching the Bitmap for you. Instead of trying retrieving the `Bitmap` from the `List` and passing it the new Activity, I strongly recommend you to pass the url of the Picture you want to show, and use `Picasso` to load it again. Passing a `String` (the bitmap's url) is way lighter than passing the whole `Bitmap` and it will definitely improve the performances

Comment: Thank you, I'm loading the image now as you suggested and it seems to work great. Picasso loads the image very quickly in the second activity and so it loads with the image very smoothly.
Seems like a better approach than my original intention.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with everything Blackbelt said. Just want to extend his answer with example how you can pass image from url using Picasso and retrieve it in new activity.

```
Intent passImage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
passImage.putExtra("image", arrayList.get(position).getImage()); // getImage() is your
method in your class
```

And this is the example how you could retrieve image in second activity.

```
Intent getImage = getIntent();
String gettingImageUrl = getImage.getStringExtra("image");
Picasso.with(SecondActivity.this).load(gettingImageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: It really helped me. Thanks!